# Should booting the same Live OS behave the exact same way on the same machine?

Tags: hardware

If I were to run a Live OS from a read-only DVD onto a computer with any given specifications, should I expect the system to boot with the

```
+ startup time
+ RAM usage
+ CPU usage
```

every boot, allowing for the RAM to be cleared between bootups?

Since the exact same OS/distro, with the exact same processes on startup will be running on the exact same hardware, what might account for any differences if not?

Comment: Not a school question.

Comment: Yes? Should an acceptable answer include tests? Or an authoritative source? What exactly is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: i would expect very slight variations due to manufacturing differences

Comment: All of these would be relevant, I think. I'm wondering whether if practically everything is held constant then the system should behave exactly everytime.

Comment: @user942937 if the operating system is installed to the internal storage medium, instead of an external storage medium like a CD or USB flash drive, would you expect it to boot the same every time if nothing else changes?

Comment: @kemotep If the operating system were installed on anything but a read-only DVD, I expect there to always be changes, e.g., to logs, updates to access times, etc.

Comment: But should those changes change the boot time significantly? For your answer does measuring a 1 second difference in boot time qualify as a significant difference? Less than 1 second?

Comment: Not really looking for significant changes in any of the three parameters mentioned. Any change is relevent to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, computers are deterministic, so you'd expect the same behavior each time. In practice, things vary:

- time taken to start up network (negotiate connection, get DHCP lease, etc.) depends on how fast the other side responds, how busy the network is, etc. And for wireless, on radio noise, etc.
- time taken to read from DVD depends on how quickly drive can find the sectors. Measure accurately enough, and this will depend on the initial position of the disc in the drive. And on how fast the motors spins up, how well the optical pickups are tracking, etc. All of that is surely temperature-dependent, so will probably be different if left to cool overnight vs. warm. Might also depend on exact power supply voltage, which might depend on exact grid voltage.
- DVD drives are surely vibration-sensitive, so more vibrations may slow it down. There is a famous video of this (with HDDs, not DVD) “[Shouting in the Datacenter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4).” You're probably not shouting at your disc drive, but e.g., maybe on a second run the machine is warmer so a fan is running faster.
- Operating systems actually try to obtain true randomness for crypto operations. Sometimes this is from dedicated, purpose-built hardware (most recent computers have a hardware random number generator); other times its from e.g., timing the exact amount of time a disk read takes. Sometimes, this true randomness might influence boot (e.g., generating a ssh server key).
- There is a lot of hard-to-observe state inside hardware. Many devices have their own firmware and processors, running tons of complicated software. Their response time likely depends on what exactly that software is doing. E.g., a disk that is running a self-test will likely respond slower.

Slight changes in the order of service startup probably won't change the amount of data that has to be read much if at all, but will change the order. Seek time on DVD drives is terrible. That means the slight changes in order can have a huge impact in terms of time.